# CSS solution to make drop-down element visible while focused

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out if there is any **pure CSS** solution to keep a drop-down element open while the input field of that element is focused? Here is an example:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

div:hover form {
  display: block;
}

form {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover Me
<form class="search">
<input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?" autofocus>
<input type="button" value="Search!">
</form>
</div>
```

The idea is to keep the form visible when the search field is focused. Because when a user starts typing the search inquiry and the mouse move out of the hover zone, the form hides, and that's very annoying.

**Side-question**: Is it possible to focus via CSS search input element each time a `<div>` is hovered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has been already proposed, but lacks browser support:

> [**9.4. The Generalized Input Focus Pseudo-class: `:focus-within`**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-focus-within-pseudo)
>
> The *`:focus-within`* pseudo-class applies to elements for which the
>   [`:focus`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#focus-pseudo) pseudo class applies.
>
> An element also matches [`:focus-within`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#focus-within-pseudo) if one of its
>   [shadow-including descendants](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-shadow-including-descendant) matches [`:focus`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#focus-pseudo).

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
div:hover form, div:focus-within form {
  display: block;
}
form {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1">Hover Me
  <form class="search">
    <input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?" autofocus>
    <input type="button" value="Search!">
  </form>
</div>
```

Meanwhile, you can use a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/aFarkas/a7e0d85450f323d5e164):

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
div:hover form, div.focus-within form {
  display: block;
}
form {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aFarkas/a7e0d85450f323d5e164/raw/"></script>
<div tabindex="-1">Hover Me
  <form class="search">
    <input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?" autofocus>
    <input type="button" value="Search!">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wait. There's actually a pure CSS solution. But there is a drawback — it only works with just one `<input>` tag, and no `<form>` tag, like this:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 0.5%;
}
input {
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
}
div:hover input {
  display: block;
}
input:focus {
  display: block !important
}
```

```html
<div>Hover Me
  <input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
  </form>
</div>
```

However, you can just make the user search the form by pressing Enter on the keyboard. Unfortunately, this requires JavaScript, which defeats the whole purpose of this post.

I've also noticed that your placeholder text doesn't really work properly, since the text "Search" is still there. There are two solutions to this — use JavaScript to fix it, or change the 'type' of the input tag to "text".

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciate the solution!